# Frattini and Derived Subgroup of $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

It is known that the derived subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is subgroup of index 12 in the group.

**1.** What is known about derived subgroup of $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$, for $n\geq 3$? (is it finitely generated?, is its index is finite in group? etc.)

**2.** What is the Frattini subgroup of $SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$, for $n\geq 2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that ${\rm SL}(n,\mathbb Z)$ is perfect for $n \ge 3$.  You can get a transvection as a commutator:

$\left[
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
,
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0  & 0 \\
0 & 1  & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\right]
=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0  & 0 \\
0 & 1  & 0 \\
1 & 0  & 1
\end{array}
\right).
$

and similarly you can get any matrix which is the identity with a single $1$ elsewhere. It is not hard to show that ${\rm SL}(n,\mathbb Z)$ is generated by matrices of this form.

I am sure the Frattini subgroup must be trivial for all $n \ge 2$. The kernels $K_p$ of the natural maps onto ${\rm SL}(n,p)$ for primes $p$ all equal to intersections of maximal subgroups, and the intersection of all of the $K_p$ is clearly trivial.

Comment: The commutators you have written actually are like commutators in lower triangular group, so the transvections with 1 at corner (upper-right or lower-left) are commutators; but what about other transvections?

Comment: Think of the above commutator relation as $[(2,1),-(3,2)] = (3,1)$. Then for any distinct $1 \le i,j,k \le n$, we have $[(j,i),-(k,j)]=(k,i)$.